# minimum regulator for 3.7v battery

Tags: voltage-regulator

i have a 9v solar panel and a 3.7v battery that gives from 2000 to 2500 mA and i want to know the requied specefecations for a regulator to run this solar panel charger

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit poorly worded, so I'll assume:

- You want a battery charger, powered by the solar panel
- The 3.7V battery is a Li-Ion battery

**Managing the Solar Panel**

I'm no expert on solar panels, but my understanding is that they have some complicated nonlinear characteristics which make it difficult to maximize their power output. You'll want to do some research on Maximum Power Point Tracking (MPPT).

**Managing the Battery**

To charge the Li-Ion battery, you'll want a proper 'CCCV' charger. These pump a Constant Current into your battery until the voltage reaches a preset level (4.2V). Then, the charger switches to applying a Constant Voltage (4.2V) to the battery until the current drops to zero.

Thus, your 'solution strategy' is to find a CCCV charge controller you like, and read the datasheet to determine what input voltage it needs. For example, the [TI BQ2954](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/bq2954.pdf) is a single-cell charge controller. Its datasheet shows that this charger expects an input of 5V. So if you used this charge controller, a 5V regulator is what you want.

Finally - be careful! Li-Ion batteries have dangerous failure modes (fire) if mishandled.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to charge a lithium ion battery with that solar panel, then you need a way to take the energy of the solar panel and put it not the battery that is safe.

For the lithium battery chemistry, you need a constant cuurent, then constant voltage charging algorithm.

In addition, you need the voltage of the solar panel to be brought down to a maximum of 4.2 volts.  For the constant current portion of the charge, you will need to make sure that the panel does not exceed 2000 - 2500 mA or 1C, C being the capacity of the battery.

Check this [out](http://www.prodctodc.com/5a-constant-current-led-driver-lithiumion-battery-charger-digital-ampvolt-mete-p-428.html#.VUca0jXDhJ8)

Using this device between your panel and your battery and it will charge your battery safely, once you dial in the 4.2 max volts, and 2000 - 2500 max mA.

Good luck